# receive post information with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, post

I have an order form with data. on submit the controller function `new_blank_order_summary` is called.

the syntax for this is:

```
    function new_blank_order_summary() 
  {
      echo "orderlines: ".$this->input->post(orderlines);
      echo "customer: ".$this->input->post('customer');
      echo "period: ".$this->input->post('period');
      echo "creditlimit: ".$this->input->post('creditlimit');   

      $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_summary');

  }
```

I cannot get the post information to display or echo? my input Name and ID is `orderlines` but this is not being posted or received properly.

Apologies for the 'stupid' question.

any advice welcome.

**HTML**

```
<form id="sales_blank_order_details" action="/sales/new_blank_order_summary" method="post">


            <table >
                <tr><td>Customer</td><td>Period</td><td>UoM</td><td>Credit Limit</td><td>Balance</td><td>New Balance</td><td>Order Lines</td><td>Round to Bundle</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
            <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" value="<?php echo $customer; ?>" disabled>
               </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="period" id="period" value="<?php echo $period." to ".$newperiod; ?>" disabled>
               </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="buom" id="buom" value="<?php echo $buom; ?>" disabled>
               </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="creditlimit" id="creditlimit" value="<?php echo $creditlimit['creditlimit']; ?>" disabled>
           </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="currentbalance" id="currentbalance" value="<?php echo $creditlimit['currentbalance']; ?>" disabled>
           </td>
           <td>
            <input type="text" name="newbalance" id="newbalance" value="<?php echo $creditlimit['currentbalance']; ?>" disabled>
           </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="orderlines" id="orderlines" value="1" disabled>
           </td><td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rounduptobundle" id="rounduptobundle" checked>
           </td></tr></table>

<input type="submit" name="blank_order_lines" id="blank_order_lines" value="Save Order and Proceed">

</form>
```

None of these posts are outputted by controller.

Comment: `orderliness`with double s?

Comment: sorry Mudshark, typo :-)

Comment: What does the form html look like?

Comment: why is all the input field disabled. and try to see if the html form is getting all the data you are sending or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've disabled the `orderlines` text input field so that's why it will not get posted. Remove `disabled`and it will show up in `$this->input->post()`.

Comment: so disabled inputs don't get posted? how do I stop a user from editing them and still post them? they need to be displayed so hidden wont work.

Comment: You could add a hidden field with `name="orderlines" value="1"` which will show up in post - the (disabled) visible text field doesn't need a `name` in this case, it's only there as visual feedback to the user.

Answer (score 1):

what is the name and value of your submit button. Usually the name of my submit button is name="submit" and the value is value="submit". So then I try $this->input->post('submit')=='submit'. try this in your if condition. I hope it will work. best of luck.

Comment: Thanks eddard, the if statement is working, the post of the orderlines is not though. I can place an `echo 'test'` inside the condition and it will display correctly. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function new_blank_order_summary() 
{
      echo "orlderlines: ".$this->input->post('orderlines');
      echo "customer: ".$this->input->post('customer');
      echo "period: ".$this->input->post('period');
      echo "creditlimit: ".$this->input->post('creditlimit');   

      $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_summary');

}
```

Please try this code. I didn't change a single line in it. Only I put the single quotes in the 3rd line. And, changed it's variable name is wrong so I changed it